# Testing the stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: unit-testing, testing, sql-server-2012

I wrote a stored procedure for testing another stored procedure by passing different parameters and storing the count and time taken for executing the procedure in temp table. Is a procedure better than a function?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTEST_NEW] 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COUNT INT;
    DECLARE @STARTDATETIME DATETIME;
    DECLARE @ENDDATETIME DATETIME;
    DECLARE @TimeDiff NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @SPNAME VARCHAR(50);

    DECLARE @Result TABLE
                    (
                        Cases NVARCHAR(100),
                        RecordCount INT,
                        ExecutionTime NVARCHAR(50)
                    )
    DECLARE @Search TABLE
                    (
                        ID NVARCHAR(50),
                        NAME NVARCHAR(200),
                        FMT NVARCHAR(100)
                    )

     SET @SPNAME = 'dbo.[SEARCH_VALUE]'; 
     SET @STARTDATETIME = GETDATE();

     --Case#1: Search by All
     INSERT INTO @Search
         EXEC @SPNAME @PRODUCTID = NULL,
                      @PRODUCTNAME = NULL,
                      @FORMAT = NULL

     SET @ENDDATETIME = GETDATE();  
     SELECT @COUNT= @@ROWCOUNT

     SET @TimeDiff = CONVERT(TIME, @ENDDATETIME - @STARTDATETIME);

     INSERT INTO @Result 
     VALUES ('ALL', @COUNT, @TimeDiff)

     -- Case#2 : Search by Product-ID
     INSERT INTO @Search
         EXEC @SPNAME
                   @PRODUCTID = 'ABPROD-BLACK',
                   @PRODUCTNAME = NULL,
                   @FORMAT = NULL,

      SET @ENDDATETIME = GETDATE();
      SELECT @COUNT = @@ROWCOUNT

      SET @TimeDiff = CONVERT(TIME, @ENDDATETIME - @STARTDATETIME);

      INSERT INTO @Result 
      VALUES ('PROD-ID:ABPROD-BLACK', @COUNT, @TimeDiff)

      --Case#3 : Search by FORMAT
      INSERT INTO @Search
          EXEC @SPNAME
                   @PRODUCTID = NULL,
                   @PRODUCTNAME = NULL,
                   @FORMAT = 'SCHT',

      SET @ENDDATETIME = GETDATE();
      SELECT @COUNT= @@ROWCOUNT

      SET @TimeDiff = CONVERT(TIME, @ENDDATETIME - @STARTDATETIME);

      INSERT INTO @Result 
      VALUES ('Format:SCHT', @COUNT, @TimeDiff)

      SELECT * 
      FROM @Result
END
```

Is this method correct? Or any other method? Please suggest the method.

Comment: If you **really** want good time measurements - do **not use** `DATETIME` - it has a precision of 3.33ms only. Use `TIME(7)` (or `DATETIME2(7)`) which is precise down to 100ns .....

Comment: You should define "better" they serve 2 different purposes. A function is a pretty much view with parameters and can be magnitude slower but can be used in a join. A stored procedure could be compiled with execution plan which can be reused, which would result in better performance in a lot of cases.